# Yii2: Validaciones Al Actualizar Formulario

Tags: validación, yii2

Les paso a comentar hice un formulario con sus respectivas validaciones, a la hora de escribir el nombre de usuario en el formulario, este valida si el usuario ya existe y en ese caso informa del error. Cuando el formulario es para agregar un usuario, la validación funciona perfecto, lo que no se como hacer es la validación a la hora de actualizar el formulario, porque que pasa? Si yo al usuario le actualizo solo el apellido y en el campo de nombre de usuario lo dejo como esta, salta el error que el usuario ya existe, pero en realidad ese usuario es el que estoy actualizando en ese momento, me explico?

Acá paso a dejar el código:

```
class FormUpdateUser extends model{

public $nombre;
public $apellido;
public $usuario;
public $nombre_local;
public $direccion_local;
public $localidad_local;
public $banner;
public $email;
public $telefono_usuario;
public $telefono_local_primario;
public $telefono_local_secundario;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['nombre','apellido','usuario','nombre_local','direccion_local','localidad_local','email'], 'required', 'message' => 'Campo requerido'],
        ['nombre', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^[a-z]+$/i", 'message' => 'Sólo se aceptan letras'],
        ['nombre', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^.{3,50}$/", 'message' => 'Mínimo 3 y máximo 50 caracteres'],
        ['apellido', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^[a-z]+$/i", 'message' => 'Sólo se aceptan letras'],
        ['apellido', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^.{3,50}$/", 'message' => 'Mínimo 3 y máximo 50 caracteres'],
        ['usuario', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^.{3,50}$/", 'message' => 'Mínimo 3 y máximo 50 caracteres'],
        ['usuario', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^[0-9a-z]+$/i", 'message' => 'Sólo se aceptan letras y números'],
        ['usuario', 'usuario_existe'],
        ['nombre_local', 'local_existe'],
        ['banner', 'file',
            'skipOnEmpty' => false,
            'uploadRequired' => 'Banner obligatorio', //Error
            'maxSize' => 10240*10240*1, //10 MB
            'tooBig' => 'El tamaño máximo permitido es 10MB', //Error
            'minSize' => 10, //10 Bytes
            'tooSmall' => 'El tamaño mínimo permitido son 10 BYTES', //Error
            'extensions' => 'jpg, png',
            'wrongExtension' => 'El archivo {file} no contiene una extensión permitida {extensions}', //Error
        ],
        ['email', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^.{5,80}$/", 'message' => 'Mínimo 5 y máximo 80 caracteres'],
        ['email', 'email', 'message' => 'Formato no válido'],
        ['email', 'email_existe'],
        ['email', 'trim'],
        ['telefono_usuario', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^[0-9]{6,30}+$/i", 'message' => 'Escribe un número válido'],
        ['telefono_local_primario', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^[0-9]{6,30}+$/i", 'message' => 'Escribe un número válido'],
        ['telefono_local_secundario', 'match', 'pattern' => "/^[0-9]{6,30}+$/i", 'message' => 'Escribe un número válido'],
    ];
}

public function email_existe($attribute, $params)
{

    //Buscar el email en la tabla
    $table = Users::find()->where("email=:email", [":email" => $this->email]);

    //Si el email existe mostrar el error
    if ($table->count() == 1)
    {
        $this->addError($attribute, "El email seleccionado existe");
    }
}

public function usuario_existe($attribute, $params)
{
    //Buscar el usuario en la tabla
    $table = Users::find()->where("username=:username", [":username" => $this->usuario]);

    //Si el username existe mostrar el error
    if ($table->count() == 1)
    {
        $this->addError($attribute, "El usuario seleccionado existe");
    }
}

public function local_existe($attribute, $params)
{
    //Buscar local en la tabla
    $table = Locales::find()->where("nombre=:nombre", [":nombre" => $this->nombre_local]);

    //Si el username existe mostrar el error
    if ($table->count() == 1)
    {
        $this->addError($attribute, "Este local ya existe");
    }
}
```

Esas son mis validaciones, lo que no se es de que manera puedo validar si el usuario existe pero sin que tenga en cuenta el usuario actual.

Pongamos un ejemplo:

Tengo un usuario que su nombre es "pepe", su apellido "mengano" y su nombre de usuario "pmengano".
Entro para actualizarlo y solo le actualizo el apellido, pero el campo usuario va a seguir diciendo "pmengano", bueno quiero que a la hora de actualizar se actualice sin ningún problema y no que me salte el error "este usuario ya existe" en el campo usuario.

Comment: Me parece que el problema es que no distingues entre añadir y actualizar. Obviamente si usas el mismo formulario con el mismo control de errores para ambas operaciones no te puede funcionar, es decir, deberías diferencias que operación estas realizando y en función de esa operación realizar las comprobaciones necesarias.

Comment: Claro, entiendo eso. Lo que no se si hay alguna manera en Yii de comprobar ese caso en particular.
Porque sino lo que se me ocurre es con Jquery, tomar el valor del input inicial, y comprobar si el valor inicial del input es igual al valor que hay en ese momento, que no me tome como un error porque el usuario exista. El tema que soy nuevo en Yii, y por ahi capaz hay alguna manera de hacer lo mismo sin que haga falta usar JS.
Gracias.

Comment: En yii2 existen lo que son los escenarios, para determinar si en ciertas ocasiones poner o no una validación, deberías darle una leída

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Sr1871, deberias usar escenearios, esta documentacion te puede servir https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide-es/structure-models/#validation-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ello existe los scenarios , https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models

Con el indicaras cuando quieres que actue una regla de validacion ,  en tu caso solo actuara al crear un usuario. Para esto debes:

1- En el modelo crear una constante llamada SCENARIO_REGISTER por ejemplo

2- Colocarla en la regla de validacion que deseas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3- Por ultimo añadir el escenario al modelo en la action que deseas

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Usuarios();
    $model->scenario = Usuarios::ESCENARIO_CREAR;
```